# Is there any utility that can reformat a cmake file

Tags: cmake, cmake-format

I have relatively complex cmake files and I am wondering if there is any utility that can reformat a cmakeList.txt and beautify it for easier reading?

Some simple tricks would do the jobs, such as indenting if else endif sections and so on.

Is there any such tools?

I am using notepad++ for editing, but if there is any other tools, I can switch.

Comment: please check out [this link](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Editors_Support) for the CMake editors support overview. Some of them support indentation, but I am not sure if auto-formatting is available. I am also interested if it exists.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Someone recently wrote a CMake autoformatter called [cmake_format](https://github.com/cheshirekow/cmake_format). Still under development but should be good enough for basic CMake files.

Comment: @CarloWood, Maybe it was in 2018, but in 2020 it feels like `cmake_format` is the tool of choice, it's easy to use, and it just works

Comment: I personally like the parallels of `cmake-format` with `clang-format`, makes things easier

Comment: Now 2024 and `cmake-format` hasn't see any activity for the past 4 years. I found [`gersemi`](https://github.com/BlankSpruce/gersemi) and am considering it for a project.

Answer (score 3):

In case it is not clear from the other answers and comments.
In Ubuntu (Debian?) there is a tool called `cmake-format`, which seems to be what is called `cmake_format` in other answers.

And it worked very well for me.

```
$ apt search cmake-format
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
cmake-format/kinetic,kinetic,now 0.6.13-2 all [installed]
  source code formatter for cmake listfiles
```

```
$ cmake-format --help
usage: 
cmake-format [-h]
             [--dump-config {yaml,json,python} | -i | -o OUTFILE_PATH]
             [-c CONFIG_FILE]
             infilepath [infilepath ...]

Parse cmake listfiles and format them nicely.
...
```

The specification file is quite difficult to understand but I liked the default formatting anyway.
The best part is that it seems to normalize the capitalization of keywords which is what drives me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

I searched for a code beautifier supporting CMake, and I did not find any.

- There is [this thread](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/AStyle-or-similar-code-beautifier-td7586641.html) on CMake mailing lists, which does not provide a good solution
- [This](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/CMake-Code-Beautifier-td7585309.html) mailing list thread provides no answer too (some use emacs mode)
- I checked most of the major code beautifiers using [UniversalIndentGUI](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/) on Ubuntu. None of the provided beautifiers from the [long list](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/features.php) are working with CMake out of the box.

Looks like implementing CMake support in an existing beautifier, or writing a custom one is a great idea for a nice code project.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Atom](https://atom.io/) and its plugin [language-cmake](https://atom.io/packages/language-cmake) (you can install easily with Atom package manager).

Once both are installed, open your CMakeLists.txt and go to `Edit > Lines > Auto Indent`.

Comment: https://github.com/textmate/cmake.tmbundle is the source that inspired the atom plugin https://github.com/lucas-clemente/language-cmake . It's a nice feature of the atom, but changing editors is a non-starter for me personally.